# Convergence Criteria in R's lmer

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

In this [article](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAEahUKEwi1sLvX7JTHAhXTCI4KHdMtAbE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.upa.pdx.edu%2FIOA%2Fnewsom%2Fmlrclass%2Fho_sample%2520size.pdf&ei=iofDVbXDFdORuATT24SICw&usg=AFQjCNEIDdtEAQ99e5uLyKgXAFPk-N0slg&bvm=bv.99556055,d.c2E) , it is written in the **Convergence and estimation bias** para that :

> It is important to consider the minimum number of cases needed to ensure the model
>   converges and that sample estimates are not biased. In my experience, most simple models with 50
>   or more groups and approximately 5 cases per group will not have convergence problems. More
>   cases may be needed for convergence if the model is more complex, when there is more missing
>   data (unbalanced N), and when more slope variances are estimated (Raudenbush, 2008).

I have a two-level model with one explanatory variable at the individual level(X) and one explanatory variable at the group level (Z) :

$$Y_{ij}=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{10}X_{ij}+\gamma_{01}Z_j+\gamma_{11}X_{ij}Z_j+u_{0j}+u_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}$$

I am doing a simulation study for determining sufficient sample size that produces accurate estimates of the parameters of the model . I am using `lmer` under package `lme4` in `R` to fit the model . But when I have sample size $5$ at lower level , it produces many warning message about convergence. It seems to me this non-convergence issue is followed by that as I have a complex model more
cases is needed for convergence which is mentioned in the above article. I have checked it also by `lme` under package `nlme` and though it fits the model , but if I try to construct confidence interval by `intervals` , it gives error that :

> Error in intervals.lme(fit) : 
>   cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance

But I am in doubt because the paper I am using give results when there is 5 cases in each group and they have used MLwiN . As far I know , there is an  issue in the method of evaluating an approximation to the log-likelihood which varies.

Douglas Bates replied about  [valid estimates using lme4](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q4/017099.html) in the context of GLMM that :

> In some ways I think that reliable optimization of
>   the approximate log-likelihood is more important and that is an area
>   where R is not strong.  Far too much optimization code is covered by
>   licenses that are not compatible with R's license and the pickings for
>   Open Source optimization code are somewhat slim.  I wish I had access
>   to some of the optimizers that SAS uses but we don't so we make use of
>   what we do have.

Is it applicable also in the context of `lmer` so that I am facing non-convergence criterion where as MLwiN overcome the difficulties ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that that the exempt from D. Bates' e-mail should be taken with a considerable grain of salt. It reflects the state of `lme4` fours years back from now. The default optimiser is now [BOBYQA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOBYQA) which is quite strong in comparison with what they had earlier (I think some variant of N-M simplex but I might be wrong). Similarly the use of  [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (through [RcppEigen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/index.html)) was in its infancy. You are talking about a package that (cont.)

Comment: significantly evolved (spearheaded due to B. Bolker) in the last years. For what is worth `lme` is still using EM to get initial estimates and then goes ahead and uses `nlminb`. This a different approach than the derivative-free approach used by `lmer`. Clearly in edge cases where one has small samples differences will be noticeable if not significant.

Comment: I am reading this paper http://joophox.net/publist/methodology05.pdf and try to reproduce their results, but I don't use MLwiN. Would like to post you R code here? I know you can set your own converge criterion in SAS either to a bigger number or a smaller number than the default criterion. I don't know  if you can do that in R